# Android - Capturing an image with the camera and adding an overlay with different aspect ratios

Tags: android, bitmap, overlay, android-camera, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to take an image captured from the camera and place a photoframe or overlay over it.  The photoframe is basically a png image placed in an `ImageView` within a `FrameLayout` that also contains the SurfaceView.  The problem is that I must scale either or both of the resulting bitmaps of the view containing the photo image and the photo frame image in order for the overlay to be placed in exactly the correct position over the captured photo image.  But since they have different aspect ratios, I'm at a loss to figure out how to do this without either the photo or the overlay from getting distorted.  Here is my code that handles the bitmap manipulations.  In addition, I sometimes get OutofMemory exceptions due to the huge size of the bitmaps.  I tried to use `MappedByteBuffer`but couldn't get that to work right either... sigh.  Anyway, any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong or code samples that show a better way to accomplish this are greatly appreciated!

```
    private void saveTempPhoto(byte[] data) {
    // Need to flip back the photo frame on front facing camera.
    if (this.isCameraFront)
        this.flipPhotoFrame();

    findViewById(R.id.close_button).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.flash_button).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.focus_button).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.take_photo).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
    options.inDither = false;
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true; 
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024];
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    Bitmap bitmapPhoto = null;
    Bitmap bitmapPhotoFrame = null;
    Bitmap bitmapCanvas = null;

    View view = findViewById(R.id.top_photo_frame); //view containing the photoframe

    try {
        int photoFrameWidth = view.getWidth();
        int photoFrameHeight = view.getHeight();

        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);

        if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
            //Swap height and width
            int temp = options.outWidth;
            options.outWidth = options.outHeight;
            options.outHeight = temp;
        }

        // Calculate the best sample size to use based on the ratio of the captured image to the photoframe.
        // This is done to prevent OutofMemoryExceptions from occurring, as the bitmap allocations can use up a lot of heap space.
        float ratioWidth = (float)options.outWidth / (float)photoFrameWidth;
        float ratioHeight = (float)options.outHeight / (float)photoFrameHeight;
        float ratio = Math.min(ratioWidth, ratioHeight);

        if (ratioWidth > 1 || ratioHeight > 1) {
            double power = Math.log(ratio) / Math.log(2);
            options.inSampleSize = (int) Math.pow(2, Math.round(power));
        }

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        Bitmap bitmapPhotoPreRotate = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
        int postRotation = isCameraFront ? -orientation : orientation;

        if (orientation != 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(postRotation);

            bitmapPhoto = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapPhotoPreRotate, 0, 0, bitmapPhotoPreRotate.getWidth(), bitmapPhotoPreRotate.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            bitmapPhotoPreRotate.recycle();
        }

        else
            bitmapPhoto = bitmapPhotoPreRotate;

        Log.d("PhotoFrameActivity", String.format("Photo bitmap has width %d and height %d", bitmapPhoto.getWidth(), bitmapPhoto.getHeight()));
        Log.d("PhotoFrameActivity", String.format("PhotoFrame bitmap has width %d and height %d", view.getWidth(), view.getHeight()));

        int photoWidth = bitmapPhoto.getWidth();
        int photoHeight = bitmapPhoto.getHeight();

        Bitmap.Config photoConfig = bitmapPhoto.getConfig();

        bitmapCanvas = Bitmap.createBitmap(photoWidth, 
                photoHeight, photoConfig);

        if (bitmapCanvas != null) {
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapCanvas);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapPhoto, new Matrix(), null);
            bitmapPhoto.recycle();
            bitmapPhoto = null;
            System.gc(); //Try to force GC here to free up some memory

            bitmapPhotoFrame = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                    this.loadBitmapFromView(view), 
                    photoWidth, 
                    photoHeight, 
                    true);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapPhotoFrame, 0, 0, null);
            bitmapPhotoFrame.recycle();

            Log.d("PhotoFrameActivity", String.format("Combined bitmap has width %d and height %d", bitmapCanvas.getWidth(), bitmapCanvas.getHeight()));

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmapCanvas.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

            byte[] jpegWithPhotoFrame = stream.toByteArray();

            try {
                createPhotoFile();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photoFile);
                fos.write(jpegWithPhotoFrame);
                fos.close();
                Log.d("PhotoFrameActivity", String.format("Image file saved to %s", photoFile.getPath()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (bitmapCanvas != null)
                bitmapCanvas.recycle();

            if (bitmapPhoto != null)
                bitmapPhoto.recycle();

            if (bitmapPhotoFrame != null)
                bitmapPhotoFrame.recycle();
        }
    }

    catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        // Put up out of memory alert
        AlertDialog dialogError = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        dialogError.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                finish();
            }
        }
                );
        dialogError.setMessage("Out of memory!");
        dialogError.show();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```